# Rails: set model attribute using a time reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, status

#### 1. The environment

I have an Auction model with these attributes:

- status:string
- close_date:datetime

Status of my auctions must be, automatically, set to 'ended' when Time.now
equals auction.close_date.
To do so, I think I need a way to check for this equality every second.

This is my method:

```
def set_ended
  auctions = Auction.all.active # named_scope to get only 'active' auctions
  auctions.each do |auction|
    if auction.close_date == Time.now
      auction.status = 'ended'
    end
end
```

#### 2. The question:

How can I set my application to run this method every second?

Comment: Not an answer but you might want to push the `auction.close_date == Time.now` check down into the database too, especially if you want to do this every second. Also, do you really need 1s resolution on this? Seems a little excessive to me when one minute or even half hour resolution would probably work just as well.

Comment: I agree with mu - you can resolve this on view without having a status column. There is no need to set it to end, when you can check within the view if the auction.close_date < Time.now.

Comment: Thanks @mu and @Joe, I've implemented your approach. No need for a status field.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Whenever](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby), that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks @johnny, going to check it out.